# Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); appending previous output with each new execution?

Tags: java, runtime.exec

I am running into this problem.
my program invokes `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);` on a windows platform. I read the error and output stream and do something with this output. This method gets called in a loop after each 4-5 seconds and it goes on till the program is terminated.

Now what happens, each time i read the output, the previous output is appended to the new output and as such with each iteration the result grows bigger and bigger. Is there anyway to stop this thing. The command executed is "tasklist" with some filtering parameters.

I have made a method (which returns String output) for this Runtime.getTuntime().exec(cmd) in which i am also closing the process after execution but when it is called from within the loop, each time previous output is appended to the new one.

Here is the code:

```
class Track implements Runnable {

static int size = 0;

public void run() {

    String cmd1 = "tasklist /fo list /fi \"imagename eq java.exe\"";
    String cmd2 = "tasklist /fo list /fi \"imagename eq javaw.exe\"";
    String text = "";
    int i=1, j=0;

    while(size < 100000){

        try{
            text = fList.pList(cmd2, 1);
            if (text.indexOf("javaw.exe")== -1){
                text = fList.pList(cmd1, 1);
            }
            if(j==22) System.out.println(text);
            if (text.charAt(0)!= '0') continue;
            i = text.lastIndexOf("Mem Usage:    ")+14;
            text = text.substring(i);
            text = text.substring(0,text.lastIndexOf(" K"));
            text = text.replaceFirst(",", "");
            size = Integer.parseInt(text);
            System.out.println(size);
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            j++;

        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Memory utlization exceeded the permissible limit");
    System.out.println("Now terminating the Program\n");
    System.exit(1);


}

static void memoryCheck(int size) throws Exception{

    (new Thread(new Track())).start();

}

}
```

in class fList is the method pList:

```
static String pList(String cmd, int eval) throws Exception{ //can execute external command

    String out = "";
    int val = 5; // should not be zero, to verify returned code zero for normal exec.
    try
    {            
        //String osName = System.getProperty("os.name" );

        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
        // any error message?
        eProcList error = new eProcList(proc.getErrorStream());            

        // any output?
        eProcList output = new eProcList(proc.getInputStream());

        // kick them off
        error.start();
        output.start();


        // any error???
        int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
        out = eProcList.procList();
        val = exitVal;        
        proc.destroy();
        proc.getInputStream().close();
        proc.getErrorStream().close();

    } catch (Throwable t)
    {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
    if (eval==1) return val + out;
        return out;
}
```

---

```
class eProcList extends Thread
{
    InputStream iStream;
    static String oPut = "";
    eProcList(InputStream iStream)
    {
        this.iStream = iStream;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line=null;
            while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
                oPut = oPut + line+"\n";
            } catch (IOException e)
              {
                e.printStackTrace();  
              }
    }

    static public String procList(){
        return oPut;
    }
}
```

---

you asked so iv'e copied all here.

Comment: You should post the code responsible for reading the output.

Comment: Java class names should start with capital letters `LikeThis`.  It's a convention that makes code much easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made `oPut` a `static` field -  its initialized to `""` once when the class is loaded and then shared between every new instance of `eProcList`, i.e. never cleared of the previous run. Either don't make it `static` (why is it static?) or clear it in the constructor.

Comment: i had to because, it gives compile time error.  
  
java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field oPut

Comment: @Sara - remove the static qualifier from `oPut` and `public String procList()`.  Then read up on `static`: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html

Comment: Thank you so so much.  
You solved the issue. I always ignored giving attention to those variable types and used static mostly, now i realize the porblem with it. Thanks again!!  

Actually apart from removing the static qualifier, i had to change eProcList.procList to out = output.procList()+error.procList();

Comment: @Sara - glad to help.  Don't forget to be a good StackOverflow netizen by upvoting and accepting the answer.